# Получаю ошибку при попытке сборки fluter buid appbundle

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Не сильно понимаю в мобилках, прошу помощи более опытных товарищей. пробовал делать  flutter clean.  Перевел на androidX но ошибка все еще осталась, наверное как предупреждение. Запускаться приложенька тоже перестала.
Ошибка следующая:

```
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:24:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:478:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:346:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildAppBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/android/app_bundle.dart:43:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      BuildAppBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_appbundle.dart:43:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:559:18)
#6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#12     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#13     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#14     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Ниже хвост лога (ограничение по символам не дает целый выложить)

```
    C:\PhpStormProjects\flutter_app>flutter build appbundle -v

 transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest
                        transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDynamicProfile
                        transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDynamicRelease
                        transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForProfile
                        transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease
                        transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
                        transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebugAndroidTest
                        transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDynamicProfile
                        transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDynamicRelease
                        transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForProfile
                        transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
                        transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
                        transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDynamicProfile
                        transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDynamicRelease
                        transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForProfile
                        transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugUnitTest
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDynamicProfile
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDynamicProfileUnitTest
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDynamicRelease
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDynamicReleaseUnitTest
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProfile
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProfileUnitTest
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
                        transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForReleaseUnitTest
                        validateSigningDebug
                        validateSigningDebugAndroidTest
                        validateSigningDynamicProfile
                        validateSigningDynamicRelease
                        validateSigningProfile
                        validateSigningRelease
                        writeDebugApplicationId
                        writeDebugModuleMetadata
                        writeDynamicProfileApplicationId
                        writeDynamicProfileModuleMetadata
                        writeDynamicReleaseApplicationId
                        writeDynamicReleaseModuleMetadata
                        writeProfileApplicationId
                        writeProfileModuleMetadata
                        writeReleaseApplicationId
                        writeReleaseModuleMetadata

                        Rules
                        -----
                        Pattern: clean<TaskName>: Cleans the output files of a task.
                        Pattern: build<ConfigurationName>: Assembles the artifacts of a configuration.
                        Pattern: upload<ConfigurationName>: Assembles and uploads the artifacts belonging to a configuration.
                        1 actionable task: 1 executed
    [  +16 ms] Resolving dependencies... (completed in 5,5s)
    [   +1 ms] Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
    [   +3 ms] executing: [C:\PhpStormProjects\flutter_app\android\] C:\PhpStormProjects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true -Ptarget=lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=false -Ptarget-platform=android-arm bundleRelease
    [+2090 ms] > Configure project :app
    [   +1 ms] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    [        ] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    [        ] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    [   +1 ms] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    [        ] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    [        ] WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
    [        ] It will be removed at the end of 2019.
    [        ] For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
    [        ] To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
    [        ] WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
    [        ] It will be removed at the end of 2019.
    [        ] For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
    [        ] To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
    [ +378 ms]          *********************************************************
    [   +1 ms] WARNING: This version of firebase_core will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
    [        ]          See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
    [        ]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
    [        ]          *********************************************************
    [ +487 ms] Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... (completed in 3,0s)
    [   +4 ms] "flutter appbundle" took 9 828ms.
    [        ] "flutter appbundle" took 9 828ms.
    Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:24:3)
    #1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:478:5)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:346:14)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      buildAppBundle (package:flutter_tools/src/android/app_bundle.dart:43:10)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #4      BuildAppBundleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_appbundle.dart:43:11)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #5      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:559:18)
    #6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
    #7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
    #8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
    #9      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
    #10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
    #11     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
    #12     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
    #13     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
    #14     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
    #15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
    #16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
    #17     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
    #18     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
    #19     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
    #20     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
    #21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, проблема оказалась в кривом пути к ключу для подписи релиза. Ошибка появилась только после того как я начал гулять по веткам флатера, примечательно, что она отобразилась только в мастере `flutter channel master`